# DOM Level 3 and HTMLElement

Tags: dom

I'm comparing DOM Level 2 and DOM Level 3 (http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR).  I understand DOM Level 2 has different parts such as "Core" and "HTML", and that e.g. the HTMLElement interface is defined in the DOM Level 2 "HTML" part.

Are the HTML-specific definitions part of DOM Level 3 as well?  As with Dom Level 2 Core, DOM Level 3 Core does not cover the HTML-specific definitions.  However I don't see any DOM Level 3 "HTML" part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, there is no DOM Level 3 HTML specification. However, DOM Level 2 HTML is being superseded by the HTML5 specification.

For example, the HTMLElement interface is defined here:

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/elements.html#htmlelement

---

Incidentally, DOM 3 Core is also in the process of being superseded by DOM4.

See http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html